# create a histograms for a row in a dataset with classification of 1 and 0

Tags: python, data-science

Here is the dataset:
[image: dataset]

I create a histogram of `BMI` from the database with both classification 1 and 0.

```
df.hist(column='BMI',bins =30)
```

[image: histogram]

Now, I need it to look like this:

[image: histograms of class 1 and class 0]

The classification is the outcome. How can I create 2 separate histograms with classification 1 and 0 with python.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `subplots` in the `matplotlib` module.

Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Define axes and the figure. 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(5, 3))

#Plot the left subplot: first filter df by outcome == 0 and then plot
df[df["Outcome"] == 0].hist(column = "BMI", bins= 30,  ax = axes[0])
#Right hand plot. 
df[df["Outcome"] == 1].hist(column = "BMI", bins= 30, ax = axes[1])
```

See below for plot with random data:

[image: Example using some random data]